# How can I quickly set the iPhone deployment target in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, deployment, build, settings

I was reading this [great article about Base SDK and Deployment targets](http://www.clarkcox.com/blog/2009/06/23/sdks-and-deployment-targets/) and decided to try it out myself. The Deployment target seems to be buried in the Build settings, and not that easy to access compared to the Base SDK target (which is right there in the General tab of the project settings). To get to the Deployment settings now I have to Get Info, go to the Build tab, then search for "Deployment".

Is there a quick way to check and access the Deployment target in Xcode that I'm missing?

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Never use the build pane. Just put the setting in your xcconfig files, and then it's easy to maintain, easy to find, and easy to comment. I have a [detailed talk](http://robnapier.net/blog/build-system-1-build-panel-360) on how to convert from the Build Pane to xcconfig files and why you'd want to.

Comment: xcconfig files are a great and underused feature